# Screen is dimmed and does not undim even after the back button is pressed (app is hanged)

Tags: android

After I return back to my previous activity screen, it is greayed and does not get normal even after pressing the back button.

I have to force close the app from settings (HOME -> *Settings* -> *Manage Application* -> force close app). What could be the possible problem?